# using (IDisposable) vs. class field - correct usage of ReaderWriterLockSlim

Tags: c#, using-statement, readerwriterlockslim

In a `FileWriter` class that will be used by different threads, I currently use a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` to prevent errors occurring when two threads try to write to the file at the same time like this:

```cs
(1)

public class FileWriter
{
    private ReaderWriterLockSlim readerWriterLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    public void WriteToFile(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            this.readerWriterLock.EnterWriteLock();    
            // the writing happens here
        }
        finally
        {
            this.readerWriterLockSlim.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}
```

which **does work**. But after that, I read that `ReaderWriterLockSlim` implements `IDisposable`, and so I wondered whether

```cs
(2)

public class FileWriter
{
    public void WriteToFile(string message)
    {
        using (ReaderWriterLockSlim readerWriterLockSlim = new ReaderWriterLockSlim())
        {
            readerWriterLockSlim.EnterWriteLock();
            // the writing happens here
            readerWriterLockSlim.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}
```

would be the "better" approach and whether it **might introduce some new drawbacks**. My gut feeling tells me that **I probably shouldn't create a new `ReaderWriterLockSlim` every time** the method is called but rather only once as in `(2)`.

Sadly though, **it does not work** (it's as if I hadn't even used a lock) and so I figured that `(2)` can't be correct. 
But then again, why would `ReaderWriterLockSlim` implement `IDisposable` if it wasn't planned to be used as in `(2)`?

---

**What is the correct usage of `ReaderWriterLockSlim`?**

Comment: A FileWriter that allows multiple _readers_ ? Something isn't named right.

Comment: @bommelding right, the actual use case is kind of more complex and so I had to come up with something more MVCE complying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not every `IDisposable` is *directly* used in a `using` statement. The other pattern is if you have an `IDisposable` in one of your classes *fields* (and your class "owns" that object<sup>1</sup>), then *your class* should also implement `IDisposable` and clean up *its* disposables during `Dispose`.

You're correct that your re-write is wrong, since *every caller is using a different lock object* and so no exclusion is happening.

See [Dispose Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern):

> DO implement the Basic Dispose Pattern on types containing instances of disposable types. See the [Basic Dispose Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern#basic_pattern) section for details on the basic pattern.

---

<sup>1</sup>Thanks to [Dirk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2035029/dirk)'s comment for the important caveat. If you're in a situation where you're not trying to control an object's lifetime, it's not appropriate to `Dispose` of such objects

Comment: Thank you for the clarificiation. I didn't even know the part about classes having `IDisposable` members should themselves implement `IDisposable`. I will accept the answer as soon as SO will let me.

Comment: I'd like to point out that only classes that **own** disposable members should take care of disposing such resources. An example where the class should not dispose a disposable member would be the case of dependency injection.